# In Visual Studio 2010, How do I remove XmlSerializer to use DataContractSerializer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, datacontractserializer

I created a .NET 4.0 WCF web service and put it up on our internal server.

Now, I am testing this with a simple project that queries the web service.

However, I have found that all of my property names have been appended with the **k_BackingField** string.

```
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(Name="<WoNumber>k__BackingField", IsRequired=true)]
    public string WoNumberk__BackingField {
        get {
            return this.WoNumberk__BackingFieldField;
        }
        set {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.WoNumberk__BackingFieldField, value) != true)) {
                this.WoNumberk__BackingFieldField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("WoNumberk__BackingField");
            }
        }
    }
```

I did a search on this **k_BackingField** parameter, and found this link to be my best reference:

[how to command serializer not to put k__backingfield](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/990035a5-9dab-4d97-ac69-f8b4d914f489/)

Apparently, I have somehow used the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) instead of the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx).

What I can't seem to find is how to "undo" the **XmlSerialization** and enable the **DataContractSerializer**.

In my project, I have tried searching the entire project for the following XML keywords, but they do not seem to be pulling up:

- XmlSerializerFormat
- System.Xml.Serialization
- XmlSerialzer

Does anyone know how to remove **XmlSerialization** and then re-add my Service Reference using a **DataContractSerializer**?

Or, does my WCF Service need to be modified so that it exposes the Serializer I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't that you used the `XmlSerializer` - the issue is that you're using some classes declared with the `[Serializable]` attribute on your service, and using automatic properties on that class.

The semantic of types decorated with the `[Serializable]` attribute as used by the serializers is that its **fields** will be serialized (not its properties). With automatic properties, the compiler will generate the "backing fields", and when you create a proxy (add a service reference) to the service, it will by default attempt to create a data contract equivalent to the contract in the server.

To fix this you have a few choices, by changing the *server-side* code:

- Don't use `[Serializable]`, instead using the `[DataContract]` model (which requires decorating the properties you want serialized with `[DataMember]`
- Keep `[Serializable]`, but don't use properties, use fields instead
- (if applicable) use POCO serialization (public fields / properties will be serialized), no attribute required.

Another alternative is to share the contract between the server and the client (i.e., don't use Add Service Reference, and copy the data / service contracts from the service project to the client one).

Comment: Sounds good. So, if one of my `[DataMember]` fields of my `[DataContract]` returns the custom class **MyClass1**, does this class also have to have a `[DataContract]` and have all of its methods declared using the `[DataMember]` decoration?

Comment: I didn't hear back from you, so you know what I did? I tried it. First, I tried it without **DataContracting** my class - shit didn't work. So, I tried it again after pasting `[DataMember]` on all my Properties, `[DataContract]` to the class, and giving it a declaring a blank `[ServiceContract]` interface for it. Shit DID work! Problem solved! :)

Comment: Not necessarily, you can mix / match serialization attributes *in different classes*. Just notice that if you add the `[Serializable]` in that class **MyClass1** you'll be using the `[Serializable]` programming model - i.e., fields being serialized.